# FormComponents have common isVisible method

Tags: java, wicket

Is there someway i can have several different wicket components have the same implementation of isVisible()

for instance i have Labels, TextFields, DropdownChoices and etc that have the same isVisible method but i dont wont to implement custom classes for all of them since is hard to maintain changes to the code.

btw i can't put them in a webmarkupcontainer due to the design of the page.

I want them all to inherit something like this.

```
public class DepositoryFormComponent extends Component
{
public DepositoryFormComponent(String id) {
    super(id);
}

public DepositoryFormComponent(String id, IModel model) {
    super(id, model);
}

public boolean isVisible() {
    return isFormDepositoryType();
}

protected boolean isFormDepositoryType() {
    return getCurrentSelections().getSelectedOwnedAccount().getAssetType() == AssetType.DEPOSITORY;
}

protected CurrentSelections getCurrentSelections() {
    return (CurrentSelections) getSession().getAttribute(CurrentSelections.ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
}

public void onRender(){};
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options:

1. If you've got control over the markup, and can group in a single tag all the components you want to control visibility of, you could use a [`<wicket:enclosure>`](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/wickets-xhtml-tags.html#Wicket%2527sXHTMLtags-Elementwicket%253Aenclosure) tag to make a Component control visibility of an entire piece of markup. Notice this won't affect page design, and would achieve a similar effect as to adding a `WebMarkupContainer`
2. You could add to those components an `IBehavior` that will calculate visibility and call `setVisible()` on the `Component`. You can also invoke [`Component#setVisibilityAllowed()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#setVisibilityAllowed%28boolean%29) if you don't want future calls to `setVisible()` to alter the `Component`'s visibilty. Maybe not exactly as overriding `isVisible`, but I think it'll be unlikely to achieve an override if you don't create custom components.

   ```
   public class VisiblityControlBehavior extends AbstractBehavior { 

       private boolean isComponentVisible() { 
           return isFormDepositoryType();
       } 

       protected boolean isFormDepositoryType() {
           return getCurrentSelections().getSelectedOwnedAccount().getAssetType() == AssetType.DEPOSITORY;
       }

       protected CurrentSelections getCurrentSelections() {
           return (CurrentSelections) getSession().getAttribute(CurrentSelections.ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
       }

       @Override 
       public void bind(Component component) { 
           boolean visible = isComponentVisible(); 
           component.setVisible(visible); 
           component.setVisibilityAllowed(visible); 
       } 
   }
   ```